# JPA tables are not generating

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

I am using eclipse Mars 2.0. I am working with JPA framework, recently i updated my eclipse to mars 2.0 and after that JPA framework is not working properly. I tried to install new plugins what a JPA needs but then also its not working properly. whenever i generate table from entities and make it finish a pop up box came with a message i.e. an error occured during launch. posting step by step image from which exactly problem could understand.

Please help me out.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1Oad.png]

### [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9oQE.png]

Comment: Try to check the error log `Window > Show View > Error Log`

Comment: What version of Eclipse were you on before?

Comment: Previous version was Kepler

Comment: @kftse THX ! #beer